# GridControl fill (NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, datatable, nullreferenceexception, gridcontrol

I have devexpress gridcontrol which I want to fill with data from predefined DataTable. This is my code:

```
private void SortDataTable()
{
        DataView dv = GetDataTejbl.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = comboEdit.Text + " " + "DESC";
        DataTable SortedDataTable = dv.ToTable();
        gridControl1.DataSource = SortedDataTable;
}
```

The error I get:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

- check to determine if the object is null before calling the method
- use the "new" keyword to create an object instance
- get general help for this exception

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much

EDIT: The code I've tried

```
if (GetDataTejbl.Rows.Count > 0)
```

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void SortDataTable(){

DataView dv = GetDataTejbl.DefaultView.Sort = "["+comboEdit.Text + "] DESC";
DataTable SortedDataTable = dv.ToTable();
if(SortedDataTable!=null){
 gridControl1.DataSource = SortedDataTable;
```

}
}

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that my datatable was empty (I did very poor data "transfer"). Your code helped me to realize that my DataTable was empty.

Comment: Glad, it helped you. Cheers.